# What's the difference between ArrayList<Integer> a[]; and ArrayList<Integer> a;?

Tags: java

What is the difference in adding the [] to an ArrayList `a`, as opposed to initializing like ArrayList `b`? Is there any purpose for one way or the other?

```
ArrayList<Integer> a[];
ArrayList<Integer> b;
```

Comment: The same as the difference between a `int[]` and an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<Integer> b;` is declaring a reference to an array list that contains integers, named b.
`ArrayList<Integer> a[];` is declaring a reference to an array of array lists that contain integers, named a.

`ArrayList<Integer> a[]` is the same as `ArrayList<Integer>[] a`.

Answer (score 0):

One is list of integers 
Another is array of list of integers